# iTextSharp pdfStamper.GetPdfLayers() KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, layer

A little background: I'm using iTextSharp to pre-fill Adobe Sign fields and show/hide relevant layers. The PDF was created in InDesign and exported as an Adobe PDF (Interactive) with Acrobat Layers.

When trying to access the layers using {stamper}.GetPdfLayers() I was getting a **KeyNotFoundException** thrown.

Source to replicate the problem:

```
string __sourceFileName = @"C:\Test\agreement.pdf";
string __destFileName = @"C:\Test\agreement - Updated.pdf";

using (FileStream outFile = new FileStream(__destFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(__sourceFileName);
    PdfStamper pdfWriter = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile);

    var __layers = pdfWriter.GetPdfLayers();

    pdfWriter.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();
}
```

I downloaded the iTextSharp source and traced this error to the **AddOrder** function on line 1802 of PdfStamperImp.cs in the source path of "src\core\iTextSharp\text\pdf".

The specific error occurs on line 1808 where a key that doesn't exist is used to query the Dictionary:

```
layer = ocgmap[obj.ToString()];
```

the simplest way to fix was to alter this single line to the following:

```
layer = (ocgmap.ContainsKey(obj.ToString())) ? ocgmap[obj.ToString()] : null;
```

Once the source was rebuild, PDF layers were then returned without an error.
I hope this helps anyone else who comes across the error.

iTextSharp source is available on GitHub: https://github.com/itext/itextsharp

Comment: When you ask and answer your own question, you need to post a **question** followed by an **answer** in the appropriate places. There are even options to do this when you hit the 'ask question' button. Please follow the established format of the site.

Comment: But other than that, keep up the good work! Why not also submit a pull request to the original repo with your bug fix?

Comment: Thanks, must have missed that. Will do a pull request in the next week, following the guidelines as I'm not familiar with using GIT.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, not an actual question. Issue resolved. Will do a GIT pull as per J Steen's note.